# Link to Nokia X app

Tags: android, nokiax

we're currently porting our android apps to nokia x, and so we would like to link to the apps that we have in the store. I could not find any resources on linking to these apps like it is on google play

```
market://?details
```

or

```
amzn://apps/android
```

on amazon.

How can I do that on Nokia X? The default solution with market:// does not work. It says Activity not found exception in the emulator (I don't have a real Nokia X here unfortunately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this tutorial, market:// URI should work.

[http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Deep_Linking_to_Store_on_Nokia_X](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Deep%5fLinking%5fto%5fStore%5fon%5fNokia%5fX)

You should open it like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.nokia.app.mixradio.client"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is not working on the emulator I think. It should work on a real device.